# prevent check on checkbox triggered onBlur

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I create a dropdown menu use onFocus and onBlur. There's a reason for that I don't use onClick because onFocus and onBlur I need not to close the menu manually if I have multiples dropdowns.

```
class Dropdown extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      this.state = {
         open: false
      }
    }

   render() {
      return(
      <div
        tabIndex="1"
        onFocus={() => this.setState({open: true})}
        onBlur={() => this.setState({open: false})}
      >
        <p>Menu</p>
        <div style={this.state.open === false ? {display: 'none'} : {display: 'block'} }>
        {this.props.children}
        </div>
        </div>
      )
   }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
          <Dropdown>
            <li onClick={() => alert('link 1')}>link 1</li>
            <li onClick={() => alert('link 2')}>link 2</li>
            <input type="checkbox" label="check"/>
          </Dropdown>
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

But the problem is the checkbox will not functioning properly as it trigger onBlur.

**Demo http://jsfiddle.net/dL99rx27/**

How to prevent the onBlur to trigger when I click on the checkbox? I use onClick it doesn't have such problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to change the following statement:

```
 onBlur={() => this.setState({open: false})}
```

to

```
 onBlur={() => this.setState({open: true})}
```

Comment: then how do I close the dialog? I don't think you understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the clicked element (using mousedown) is an INPUT because inputs change the focus.
This should work, I've added a new attribute for the state called **inpClick** which will become true when input in the component is clicked.

**Check demo here**

**http://jsfiddle.net/prabushitha/ed9yxun9/1/**

```
class Dropdown extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      this.state = {open: false, inpClick:false};
    }

   render() {
      return(
      <div
        tabIndex="1"
        onFocus={() => this.setState({open: true})}
        onBlur={() => {
           if(!this.state.inpClick){
            this.setState({open: false});
           }else{
            this.setState({inpClick: false});
           }
          }
         }

          onMouseDown={(e)=>{
             if(e.target.nodeName=="INPUT"){
               this.setState({inpClick: true});
             }
            }
           }
      >
        <p>Menu</p>
        <div style={this.state.open === false ? {display: 'none'} : {display: 'block'} }>
        {this.props.children}
        </div>
        </div>
      )
   }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
          <Dropdown>
          <div>
            <li onClick={() => alert('link 1')}>link 1</li>
            <li onClick={() => alert('link 2')}>link 2</li>
            <input type="checkbox" label="check" />
            <li onClick={() => alert('link 2')}>link 2</li>
            </div>
          </Dropdown>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

React.render(<App />, document.body);
```